# Removing only certain parts of scope from scala xml object

Tags: xml, scala, namespaces, scope

For various reasons, I'd like to remove only certain parts of the scope from the following scala elem object. I realize xmlns is being defined twice which is part of the reason my program is failing, but this is what I have to work with from the service I'm calling in to.

```
val dataXML = <DataSet xmlns="" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <Table BillCycleCode="20131218" Amount="135.6200" BillEndDate="2014-01-17T00:00:00-06:00" BillStartDate="2013-12-18T00:00:00-06:00" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:id="Table1"/>
                <Table BillCycleCode="20140118" Amount="126.5500" BillEndDate="2014-02-17T00:00:00-06:00" BillStartDate="2014-01-18T00:00:00-06:00" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:id="Table2"/>
                <Table BillCycleCode="20140218" Amount="126.5500" BillEndDate="2014-03-17T00:00:00-05:00" BillStartDate="2014-02-18T00:00:00-06:00" msdata:rowOrder="2" diffgr:id="Table3"/>
              </DataSet>
```

dataXML.scope reveals the following:

```
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns=""
```

Basically I want to be able to do some sort of filter so that if(particularNamespace != xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" OR particularNamespace != xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata") remove particularNamespace.

My end result should look something like this:

```
<DataSet xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <Table BillCycleCode="20131218" Amount="135.6200" BillEndDate="2014-01-17T00:00:00-06:00" BillStartDate="2013-12-18T00:00:00-06:00" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:id="Table1"/>
  <Table BillCycleCode="20140118" Amount="126.5500" BillEndDate="2014-02-17T00:00:00-06:00" BillStartDate="2014-01-18T00:00:00-06:00" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:id="Table2"/>
  <Table BillCycleCode="20140218" Amount="126.5500" BillEndDate="2014-03-17T00:00:00-05:00" BillStartDate="2014-02-18T00:00:00-06:00" msdata:rowOrder="2" diffgr:id="Table3"/>
</DataSet>
```

I'm fairly new with working with xml in scala, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The code you need should look somewhat like this (I didn't test it, but just wrote something similar):

```
def yourFilterFunction(prefix : String) : Boolean = ....

def scopeFilter(scope : NamespaceBinding) : NamespaceBinding = 
  if (scope == TopScope) TopScope else
     if (yourFilterFunction(scope.prefix))
        new NamespaceBinding(scope.prefix, scope.uri, scopeFilter(scope.parent))
     else
        scopeFilter(scope.parent)

def removeScopes(node : Node) : Node = node match {
  case Elem(prefix, label, attr, scope, children @ _*) =>
    Elem(prefix, label, attr, scopeFilter(scope), children.map(removeScopes(_)):_*)
  case _ => node
}
```

You need to implement the filter function that return false for every unused prefix. Then you can call removeScopes on your Element node.

Good luck